# iText – HTML to PDF - Image is not displayed in PDF

Tags: java, itext, relative-path, html-to-pdf

I have a html page with text, image and I am parsing the HTML content to iText to generate the PDF. In the generated PDF,Included images are not getting displayed and , only the text is getting displayed.

If I pass the absolute path like **D:/Deiva/CRs/HTMLPage/article-101-horz.jpg** then the image will get printed. But if I try to print the image from the server like

`http://localhost:8085/content/dam/article-101-h1.jpg or http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif`

then it is not getting printed in the PDF.

**NOTE:** I am using **itextpdf-5.2.1.jar** to generate the PDF.

**My HTML Code (Article.html):**

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>   
     <p>Generate PDF with image using iText.</p>
     <img src="http://localhost:8085/content/dam/article-10-h1.jpg"></img>
     <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/imgs_logo_lg.gif"></img>
     <img class="right horz" src="D:/Deiva/CRs/HTMLPage/article-101-horz.jpg"></img>
   </body>
</html>
```

**I am using the below java code for generating the PDF:**

```
private void createPDF (){

  String path = "D:/Deiva/Test.pdf";
  PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;

  //create a new document
  Document document = new Document();

  try {

   //get Instance of the PDFWriter
   pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));

   //document header attributes
   document.addAuthor("betterThanZero");
   document.addCreationDate();
   document.addProducer();
   document.addCreator("MySampleCode.com");
   document.addTitle("Demo for iText XMLWorker");
   document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

   //open document
   document.open();
   InputStream is = new             FileInputStream("D:/Deiva/CRs/Oncology/Phase5/CR1/HTMLPage/Article.html");

   // create new input stream reader
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

   //get the XMLWorkerHelper Instance
   XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
   //convert to PDF
   worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, isr);

   //close the document
   document.close();
   //close the writer
   pdfWriter.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
```

Please suggest a solution to display the image in PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Deiva

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do it easily using a Servlet for viewing the image. How to write a servlet for this is [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Here a sample dispatcher for you. Just edit the required places as needed

```
@Controller
public class ImageController extends DispatcherServlet {



    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.

    // Properties ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private String imagePath;

   @RequestMapping(value="images/{imageId:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody void getImage(@PathVariable String imageId,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        String requestedImage = request.getPathInfo();
         this.imagePath ="image path in server here";

         if (requestedImage == null) {
             // Do your thing if the image is not supplied to the request URI.
             // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
             try {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
             }catch(IOException ioException){
                logger.error("error image path incorrect:{}", ioException);

            } // 404.
             return;
         }

         File image=null;
        try {
            image = new File(imagePath, URLDecoder.decode(imageId, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unsupportedEncodingException) {
            logger.error("error image can not decode:{}", unsupportedEncodingException);

        }

         // Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
         if (!image.exists()) {
             // Do your thing if the file appears to be non-existing.
             // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
             try {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
             }catch(IOException ioException){
                logger.error("error image does not exists:{}", ioException);

            } // 404.
             return;
         }

         // Get content type by filename.
         String contentType = "jpeg";
         contentType="image/"+contentType;

         // Init servlet response.
         response.reset();
         response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
         response.setContentType(contentType);
         response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));
         response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + image.getName() + "\"");

         // Prepare streams.
         BufferedInputStream input = null;
         BufferedOutputStream output = null;

         try {
             // Open streams.
             try {
                input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(image), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                logger.error("error creating file input stream to the image file :{}", e);


            }
             try {

                 output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            } catch (IOException e) {


                logger.error("error creating output stream to the http response :{}", e);

            }

             // Write file contents to response.
             byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
             int length;
             try {
                while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                     output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                 }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                logger.error("error writing the image file to outputstream :{}", e);

            }
         } finally {
             // Gently close streams.
             close(output);
             close(input);
         }
     }

     // Helpers (can be refactored to public utility class) ----------------------------------------




private  void close(Closeable resource) {
    if (resource != null) {
        try {
            resource.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
            logger.error("error closing resources:{}", e);
        }
    }
}




}
```

Comment: That isn't even close to a viable answer! Come on, example, references etc!! :D

Comment: @Chris : I faced the same problem and achieved it this way. Just thought it will help him, :)

Comment: Agreed, but I set the bounty because it's a question that has been largely unanswered on here, and if you want the bounty, could you place show it in more detail.

Comment: Hi @SanjayaLiyanage can you give code for my problem. my image tag will be `<img alt="" src="/testing/Image?imageId=9"/> ` where /testing/Image is my servlet mapping URL. How should i re-write the `@RequestMapping(value="images/{imageId:.+}` Here imageId value will be changing. I used the above code but it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some examples: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-images

```
htmlContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {
    public String getImageRootPath() { return "src/main/resources/html/"; }
});
```

If the HTML file you're parsing is stored in a directory that is different from the working directory, iText won't be able to create Image objects. We have to supply an implementation of the ImageProvider interface that tells iText what to do if an img tag is encountered. This interface has the following methods:

```
Image retrieve(final String src);
String getImageRootPath();
void store(String src, Image img);
void reset();
```

You can write your own class implementing these four methods, or you can subclass AbstractImageProvider. It is preferred to do the latter. XML Worker will use the store() method of the AbstractImageProvider class to cache all the Image objects that are encountered in a Map. These objects will be reused when the retrieve() method is called for an image with the same src. If you don't cache images, your PDF will be bloated. The same image bits and bytes will be written to the PDF more than once. The reset() method clears the cache; it is used when an ImageProvider is cloned. Finally, the getImageRootPath() method isn't implemented.

If the HTML file you're parsing is stored in a directory that is different from the working directory, iText won't be able to create Image objects. We have to supply an implementation of the ImageProvider interface that tells iText what to do if an img tag is encountered. This interface has the following methods:

You can write your own class implementing these four methods, or you can subclass AbstractImageProvider. It is preferred to do the latter. XML Worker will use the store() method of the AbstractImageProvider class to cache all the Image objects that are encountered in a Map. These objects will be reused when the retrieve() method is called for an image with the same src. If you don't cache images, your PDF will be bloated. The same image bits and bytes will be written to the PDF more than once. The reset() method clears the cache; it is used when an ImageProvider is cloned. Finally, the getImageRootPath() method isn't implemented. You have to implement it yourself, as is done in the following snippet:

Comment: htmlContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {

    public String getImageRootPath() {

        return "src/main/resources/html/";

    }

});

Answer (score 3):

to show image with Itext, you have to Changing the default configuration about Image Provider Like it :
i do it from http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html

```
public class HtmlToPDF1 {
  public static void main(String ... args ) throws DocumentException, IOException {    

      FontFactory.registerDirectories();
      Document document = new Document();
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
          new FileOutputStream("src/test/ressources/mypdf.pdf"));
      document.open(); HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
      htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
      htmlContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {
          public String getImageRootPath() {
              return "/home/fallphenix/workspace/JAVA/JEE/testHTMLtoPDF/src/test/ressources/";
          }
      }); CSSResolver cssResolver =
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);
        Pipeline<?> pipeline =
            new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
                    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext,
                        new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(new FileInputStream("src/test/ressources/other.html"));
        document.close();
          System.out.println("Done.");        
    }}
```

Comment: i use maven project. the import file like

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the image into a memory or byte stream object and then cast that image object to an itextsharp image one.

explore the overloads of `iTextSharp.text.Image`

**EDIT:**

***Although the code is in C#, it might help you.***

Get image from your local drive as:

```
Bitmap image1;
image1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\" 
            + @"Documents\My Music\music.jpeg", true);
```

**Note:**: If you have the image on your application folder then we have functions to get the local file path of them in C#. Don't know about Java. Images from external site can be downloaded as

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(imageURL, localPathname);   // look into java to get local path
```

Now convert this byte stream to an image object as

```
MemoryStream imgMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(imgByteArray);
Image myImage = Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgMemoryStream);
```

Now acreate an iTextSharp image object from it and add it to your doucment as

```
iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(myImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
document.Add(pic);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Saksham, Thanks for your reply, Do you have sample code in java? If you have then please share the code. It will help me to finish this task ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced to same issue..

but it was working with the image absolute path. it seems not working with remote path.
What id did here is save the image in temp location of file system and generates pdf , finally delete the image file from temp location.

```
<img src="/home/jboss/temp/imgs/img.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same requirement and this is what worked for me:

```
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        htmlContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {
        public String getImageRootPath() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Image retrieve(String src) {
            try {
                Image img = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(new URL(src));
                return Image.getInstance(img);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```